# Media Wiki JSON response

Tags: json, response, mediawiki

I am little bit new in media wiki and now I am developing a extension. I would like to print a JSON response when it’s makes a request for one of my special pages, that the extension creates. The JSON response is not a content of Wikipedia page, it’s a public key that I want to print, and only that. I find for solutions but I don’t find nothing. What it’s the best way to print that? API, Jquery, Special pages?

Answer (score 0):

The API. See [API:Extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Extensions) for instructions.